# CRM 2016 Plugin Profiler not working for some plugins

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am having an issue with the Plugin Profiler in CRM 2016 on-premise.

I need to debug a plugin on a remote machine. The assembly that contains the plugin is not registered as sandbox. Also for all plugins in the assembly, the deployment is set to Server and mode is synchronous. The solution on the remote server is managed.

I successfully installed the profiler in the Plugin Registration Tool and the Plug-in Profiler node appears in the tool as expected. However, when I select my intended plugin step to debug, there is no "Start Profiling" option available when I right click on the step or at the top of the Registration tool. In fact, that option is not available for any plugin steps in the custom assembly. However it is available for plugins in some built-in assemblies such as ActivityFeeds.Filtering.Plugins.

Any help with getting the profiler to work in appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like intermittent issue. Did you verify from other machine?

Comment: Hi Arun. By other machines do you mean other CRM front-end servers or other development machines such as those of my colleagues? I did not do either, but I unregister and re-register the profiler on the same server and still had the same issue.

Comment: Another dev machine. I never faced this partial issue. :)